# Add a friend feature in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need a simple add a friend feature in my application, through some research, I would need a join table linking back to users table ? something like this: (I already have a users table)

> Users-Friendships-Users

Can anyone give more details about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The friendships table should have following columns:

```
id Integer
user_from (the user who requested friendship)
user_to (the user who accepted friendship)
created (optional to track when your friendship started)
```

Then you need to create proper Model relation.

```
class User extends AppModel {
   ...
   var $hasMany = array(
      'UserFrom'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friendship',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
      ),
      'UserTo'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friendship',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
      )
   );
   var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'Friendship' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'joinTable' => 'friendships',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_from',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'user_to'
   );
   ...
}

class Friendship extends AppModel {
   ...
   var $belongsTo = array(
      'UserFrom'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
      ),
      'UserTo'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to'
      )
   )
   ...
}
```

This way you are defining 2 relation in each model. You can add HABTM relation too. Run bake script to build your controllers and views. Then in your code you can use something like this:

```
$this->User->UserFrom->find('all', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array('user_from'=>1), 
        'contain'=>array('UserTo')
    )
);
```

This should return friends of user with ID 1 and all friends details.

Be careful with the recursive queries. :)

Comment: Hi Nik, about HABTM relations, isn't it I need to use HABTM? if so, how would that affect the model relations you wrote above? I'm still slightly confused. and for running bake, I'd be baking friendship am I right? and may I know the last codes you wrote above where should I place it in? thanks..

Comment: shouldn't I be using a joinTable in the relation model ?

Comment: The friendship table will be the join table. I've edited my post and you can see the example HATBM definition. Actually I haven't tested in real this, but this way it should do.

Bear in mind that if you have many users HABTM is not an option, because a long list is not very convenient way to find people :)

Comment: Hi Nik, I still don't think it will work, I suspect that the table friendships has to have a foreign key named user_id. Thanks anyway. I'm trying ..

Comment: The foreign key is defined in HABTM relation so it should be be a problem.

Comment: Ok Nik, I guess I did it. Now just playing with the viewing codes. There has to be a foreign key from the friendships table. :-)