# CakePHP allow users to add other users as friends and group them

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a friend system in CakePHP for users based on this: [Add a friend feature in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911812/add-a-friend-feature-in-cakephp)

But I need to add two additional features:

1.) Users need to be able to request and confirm/cancel friend requests

2.) Users need to be able to group friends e.g. Friends, Family, Co-workers etc

Can anyone give me some ideas as to what extra tables I would need and the likely relationships between them and the existing tables.

Also based on that article it seems the relationships are based on which user asked who but I don't care much for that so what would I do to make it so it's just a relationship rather than tracking which user requested the friendship and who is the friended friend?

**NOTE: I asked a similar question earlier and had to delete it as everyone mis-understood the question. I am asking a question just like the one mentioned above and hoping to get answers like they have in terms of tables and relationships.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a field in your relationships database table called confirmed or similar. Basically when a friendship is requested a record is created, but with confirmed set to 0. When the "requestee" accepts the friendship, the confirmed field is set to 1, or if declined the record is deleted (allowing the requester to request friendship again).

To group, you'll obviously need a groups table with an ID and non-unique name field, and a `groups_relationships` table that has two columns: `relationship_id` and `group_id`. This will allow a user to place a friend into a group. You can then query the `groups_relationships` table with a `group_id` to find the IDs of friends that a member has placed in that group.

Comment: Ah I like that but I'll use status instead of confirmed as I could also use this for when people block others. Thanks

Comment: I would create a separate table to hold blocks, as you may have more than one condition that can't be expressed in one column.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Basically have a `block` table with two columns: `user_id` and `blocked_user_id`. When handling friend requests, see if the requester (`blocked_user_id`) is blocked by `user_id`. If so, give them an error message instead of creating a new friend request. Hope that helps.

Comment: But why not just have that in the same table as friendships and if status = block then show that error message?

Comment: Because you may need to use the block status elsewhere in your application that doesn't refer to a friendship. For example, what if a user just wants to block a user directly, like you can on Facebook? There wouldn't be a friendship record between the two, and a friendship record shouldn't be created just to represent a user block.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3343/discussion-between-martin-bean-and-cameron)